# Why Excel VBA can't query tables with the @ symbol?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm trying to query a table, call it history@integration.

When I query the table, with this type of query:

```
select * from history@integration where id=5
```

and get the expected output.

With excel I connect to the database in this way:

```
cn.Open ( _
"User ID=" & userID & _
";Password=" & password & _
";Data Source=" & datasource & _
";Provider=MSDAORA.1")
```

but I get a runtime error of `data type is not supported`. I've verified using the exact same connection I can query the database with other "standard" tables like `select * from history`. Any thought on how I can get the "correct" type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle (assuming this is what you're using, and it would be helpful to state that in your question) @ is typically used to represent a database link: likely it's not part of the table name, but the table "history" is actually in a different database linked to by a DB link named "integration".

Not all datatypes are selectable over an Oracle DB link (LOB types for example)

Comment: This makes complete sense. Do you have any thoughts on how I could work around this though?

Comment: Do you have large object - type columns in the table you want to query?  I think the only way around the issue is to run an " insert into select from" query to copy the records to a local temp table (which does work, even with LOB columns) and then select from the local table.

Comment: See (for example): https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1816839500346250853

Answer (score 1):

@ is a reserved character in SQL.  Try surrounding the table name with brackets like: `[history@integration]`.

Comment: I tried throwing the brackets in there and I got "invalid table name" in response. I don't use them when I query normally and get the expected output. It's only in excel when I use the @ symbol that I run into the error

Comment: I tried the brackets on both the excel and the "normal" way of querying through Toad, and I get the same response, invalid table name